# How to filter values in nested dicts which are in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-loops

I have such structure of the content:

```
content = [
{'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 1, 
   'item': 
    {'@type': 'Product', 'url': 'TestSample', 'sku': 'HO6096863EAD7E0PH', 'mpn': 'HO6096863EAD7E0PH', '@id': 'HO6096863EAD7E0PH'}},
 {'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 2, 
   'item': 
    {'@type': 'Product', 'url': 'TestSample', 'sku': 'HO5FFFA64882401PH', 'mpn': 'HO5FFFA64882401PH', '@id': 'HO5FFFA64882401PH'}}
]
```

I need to get all values with key 'url'. I used such loop and it works, but how to make it more easier? I have read about function "filter", but not sure that its suitable in my case.

```
for r in content:
    k = r.get('item', {}).get('url')
    print(k)
```

the output should be like: TestSample, TestSample

Comment: why are you unhappy  with your current code?

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? You could use comprehension to make it a bit easier: `k = [r.get('item', {}).get('url') for r in content]`

Comment: `filter` could help you to avoid skip dictionaries without one of the keys, but you can also do it with a simple `if` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Filter is used for filtering elements from an iterable, you can get elements with matching criteria.

But if you want sub element from the element you can use map function for this.

check below example, here the lambda function will take url from each item and map will apply this lambda function on each dict in your list:

```
l = list(map(lambda x:x['item']['url'],content))
print(l)
```

output is:

```
['TestSample', 'TestSample']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is `map` and not `filter`:

```
items = map(lambda x: x.get('item', {}).get('url'), content)
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

The code above will print:

```
TestSample
TestSample
```

If you want an example with `filter`:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: 'item' in x and 'url' in x['item'], content)
items = map(lambda x: x['item']['url'], filtered)
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

What filter does is checks if 'item' and 'url' are in that dictionary value and if it is then it adds it to the result, if not then it will not add it. This way you can be sure that `filtered` will always have both `item` and `url`.